# updating model's association when association gets add/removed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Foo` which `:has_many bars`, initially I create and save a `Foo` instance called `foo`. Looking at `foo.bars` it is empty as expected. But after I create a `bar` instance that `belongs` to the `foo` instance. `foo.bars` should no longer be empty but it still it. If I do `Foo.find(foo.id).bars` it returns a non-empty result as expected. Is there a way to `update` `foo` so that I don't have to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that foo.bars would have been cached by the first call. You can force it to refresh using `foo.bars(true)`

Answer (score 2):

That's probably happening because of caching.

```
foo = Foo.create! #=> executes sql, and caches the result
foo #=> retrieved from cache
foo.bars << Bar.create #=> creates the bar, and associates it with the foo instance
foo.bars #=> retrieves the bars from cache, so it's []
Foo.find(foo.id).bars #=> executes sql, and returns [<bar# id: 1>]
```

To get around that, you just create a new instance of foo, or just reload it:

```
foo.reload
```

Or, `foo.bars(true)`.